# Launching a Web Browser on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, browser

The simplest way to launch a web browser from within a blackberry app is:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(URL);
```

Is there any reason I would need to use `Browser.getSession(UID)` instead of `Browser.getDefaultSession()`?  What does that provide for the average use of opening a web browser that the default session does not, if all I'm worried about is showing the URL provided?

Comment: BB API is not informative of `Browser.getDefaultSession()`. It is unclear what transport it will use. While with `Browser.getSession(UID)` you can request a specific transport (however, DirectTCP is not supported (why??)). So I really don't know what to advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getDefaultSession() returns the session for the default browser, getSession(UID) gets the session for the connection specified by the UID which might be: BES, BIS_B, WAP, etc.

The following links provide a great deal of information on network trasports and browser sessions:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Network-Transports/ta-p/446834

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Invoke_the_browser.html?nodeid=1487366&vernum=0

Comment: If I just have a link the user clicked on (like our website on the about screen) do I really need to figure out what UID to use, or can I just use getDefaultSession?

Comment: Well that depends if you want the user to access your web site using the default session (in OS 5 and lower set by the user, OS 6 selected by the OS) or the one you choose. In most cases the default session is probably the one you want to use but you haven't provided enough information to make a reasonable decision.

Comment: Well, I'm at a bit of a loss... what sort of information lets me make that decision?  The documentation is lacking, and I haven't been able to find a good reason to use one or the other in _any_ case.  On the  iPhone, there's a simple call: openURL.  Same on the Android platform, just a simple call to open a browser and show a webpage.  Why does BlackBerry make it so complicated?  Or am I overcomplicating it and just using the default session should be fine?

Comment: The Blackberry is so complicated because it has a greater degree of flexabilitiy. For a good introduction to network trasports in Blackberry see the videos at links I will edit into my answer.

Comment: That's all very interesting, but I don't need or want to use HttpConnections, which the first two links seem to talk about.  And none of those links address the _why_.  Why would I use one over another?  I'm not developing an application for a specific client, I'm just developing an application for general public usage, and there are links to webpages in the application that I want to be clickable in the application and have the user be able to view those pages in their web browser.  Is there not some simple answer you can give for my problem?

Comment: Well, I could quite litterally go on for several pages discussing the factors and relative merrits of using one method over another, and under what conditions, in the last project I worked on, but as far as which factors are important to you, or your users I haven't a clue. The default session is the one used by the system by default. How it is selected depends on the OS, the user, and perhaps the IT policy on the device. It is the session that will be used by the browser if the user types in a URL without any other action. Will it work in most cases? Probably. In all? Probably not.